# Как называется этот разъём жёсткого диска в ноутбуке?

Tags: hdd, ssd

Я хочу заменить этот hdd на ssd или sshd. Ещё не определился с выбором. Я знаю, что этот ноутбук поддерживает только один жёсткий диск и нет способа впихнуть в него 2 (только разве что внешний жёсткий диск через usb).
Как называется этот разъём жесткого диска в ноутбуке?
Возможно ли подключить sshd к этому разъёму?
Лучше взять большой ssd (но это дорого) или sshd?
Есть ли смысл покупать внешний ssd диск (если винда на внутреннем hdd, то будут ли скорости в работе с внешним ssd большими?) ?
Благодарю за внимание.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Сам разъем-то вы и не показали. Но поскольку на диске ясно видна надпись "SATA", то очевидно, что подключается он через одноименный разъем.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Существует несколько разъёмов это:

1. SATA
2. mSATA
3. M.2

Спешу предположить что у вас в ноутбуке установлен SATA разъём.

И думаю он без проблем поддержит sshd, для более подробной информации обратитесь в гугл поисковик.